# How to pass multiple parameter from view to controller in .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to pass 2 parameters id and date from view to controller side on the click event. It may be basic question but i am not able to do so.

I tried simply this code

```
Code <a href='/Abc/Details/id?=@website_id, date?=@date' class="" id="prev" >Prev</a>
```

and how to get those parameter at controller side.

I don't want to use "Ajax" or JavaScript if possible

Comment: `.../Details?id=@website_id&date=@date"` but why are you not using `@Html.ActionLink()` to generate this correctly? - `@Html.ActionLink("Prev", "Details", "Abc", new { id = "@website_id", date = "@date" }, new { id = "prev" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke:I tried that but It dosen't work for me

Comment: Then you have made a mistake and not used the code I showed, or you have other errors in your code.

Comment: I don't receive any parameters at controller side by your suggestion. yes may be you are right but it didn't work for me that's what i am said

Comment: Then your not passing any values in the parameters - just hard code it as `@Html.ActionLink("Prev", "Details", "Abc", new { id = "1", date = "2016-2-8" }, new { id = "prev" })` to see how it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all either you need to create custom route or enable MapMvcAttributeRoutes in your routeconfig file by adding below line of code.

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Then in your controller above your defined action add something like below.

```
[Route("/Abc/Details/{id}/{date}")]
```

If you want to make it nullable then.

```
[Route("/Abc/Details/{id?}/{date?}")]
```

Your action method will be something like below.

```
[Route("/Abc/Details/{id?}/{date?}")]
public ActionResult Details(int id, string date)
```

Use @Html.ActionLink instead of hard coding your links.

If you wanted to go with custom route then add it **above your default route**.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "MyCustomRoute",
                "Archive/{entrydate}",
                new { Controller = "ABC", action = "Details",Id  = UrlParameter.Optional,Date =  UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Now in your view

```
@Html.RouteLink("Link Text", "MyCustomRoute", new { Id = YourId, Date=YourDate})
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to declare your variables in the Controller Action:

```
public IActionResult Create(string FirstName, string MiddleName, string    
LastName, string ADUsername, string ADId, string ADName, string ADemail)
{
    //do this
}
```

Then you can assign the variables by name in the View:

```
<a asp-controller="Employees" asp-action="Create" asp-route-   
FirstName="@item.FirstName" asp-route-MiddleName="@item.MiddleName" asp-
route-LastName="@item.LastName" asp-route-ADUsername="@item.ADUsername" asp-
route-ADId="@item.ADId" asp-route-ADName="@item.ADName" asp-route-
ADemail="@item.ADemail">Add Employee</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found @Mighty Ferengi answer very useful. Thanks man!

```
public IActionResult Create(string FirstName, string MiddleName, string    
LastName, string ADUsername, string ADId, string ADName, string ADemail)
{
//do this
}
```

In Razor

```
<a asp-controller="Employees" asp-action="Create" asp-route-   
FirstName="@item.FirstName" asp-route-MiddleName="@item.MiddleName" asp- route-LastName="@item.LastName" 
asp-route ADUsername="@item.ADUsername" 
asp-route-ADId="@item.ADId" asp-route ADName="@item.ADName" 
asp-route- ADemail="@item.ADemail">Add Employee</a>
```